# How can I use the .where() query in firestore to navigate between different screens? Flutter, Dart, Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in the cloud firestore 'Users', each document in the collection has a field called account type.
I want to use the .where() query to filter the documents, if it satisfies the condition it will navigate to a certain screen.

```
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;   
firestoreInstance.collection("Users").where("AccountType", isEqualTo: 1); 
// If accounttype == 1 => Navigator.pushNamed(context, Screen1.id);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the data from the Firestore and then apply your logic accordingly.

```
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;   
QuerySnapshot query = await firestoreInstance.collection("Users").where("AccountType", isEqualTo: 1).get();

if(query.docs.isNotEmpty) {
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, Screen1.id);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```dart
final element = await firestoreInstance
  .collection('Users')
  .where('AccountType', isEqualTo: 1)
  .get();

if (element.docs.isNotEmpty()) Navigator.pushNamed(context, Screen1.id);
```